# Sass: set default value to variables

Tags: sass

What is the right way to write this?

```
@mixin image-bg($bg-url, $full-page: false)
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-position: center
  background-image: asset-url($bg-url) 
  background-attachment: fixed
  @if $fullpage
    -webkit-background-size: cover
    -moz-background-size: cover
    -o-background-size: cover
    background-size: cover
```

I want to pass a $full-page variable to the @mixin. When user set $full-page to true, it would use the `cover` statements. If it is not given or set to false, it will not use the `cover` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right, except for one small mistake:

```
@if $fullpage
```

Your variable is named `$full-page`, not `$fullpage`.